# Ender 3 S1 printing issue - round bottom

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting, heated-bed

I got myself an Ender 3 S1 printer a couple of days ago and I tried printing the following [headset stand](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2050885).

The printing is still in progress. The top doesn't look too bad (unless you know how it could get better).
The problem is the "round bottom" part. The layers are really messy and looks like melted (see pictures below).

[image: Top View]

[image: Bottom view]

I tried multiple configurations with Cura and Creality Slicer. The best result, up to now, where with the following settings in Cura (it is worst with default profiles in Creality Slicer):

- Eryone PLA+
- Layer height: 0.12 mm
- Initial Layer height: 0.16 mm
- Initial Layer speed: 15 mm/s
- Print speed: 60 mm/s
- Wall speed: 30 mm/s
- Travel speed: 110 mm/s
- Initial Bed temp (otherwise there is not enough adhesion): 70 °C
- Print Bed temp: 60 °C
- Nozzle temp: 195 °C (tried with 200 and 210, 195 gives the best result so far)
- Retraction distance: 0.8 mm
- Retraction speed: 45 mm/s
- Adhesion: Brim 3 mm (cannot be bigger because of the size of the model)

Doed someone know what caused this and how to prevent it?

Comment: What is "line height"? Do you mean "layer height"? How big is the nozzle, usually 0.4 mm, the height doesn't look like 1.2 mm. Maybe you meant 0.12 mm? Note that that is a very small layer height, or improperly tuned or an uneven bed, such layers may cause over extrusion on the layers, this is what you encounter.

Comment: @0scar, yes sorry, I meant layer height and 0.12/0.16mm, sorry for the typos. The nozzle is indeed 04.mm.
I have levelled the bed just before the printing by running an auto-homing, adjusting the z-offset at the center, manually adjusting the wheels at the 4 corners with a sheet of paper and then running the auto-leveling feature of the printer.

I'm a bit of a newbie, so, if it is over extrusion, is it normal that it only affects the curved sides at the bottom? Everything else is smooth.

Answer (score 1):

So it ended up being a combination of multiple things.
To obtain the proper settings in the slicer, I started with the "standard" Ender S1 preset in Creality Slicer and then I changed the profile one at a time (from standard to super quality) doing small adjustments for each of the profiles.
I was then able to get an "OK" print of the 3DBenchy with the following settings:

- 0.12 mm Layer height
- 0.2 mm Initial Layer height (instead of 0.16 mm)
- Nozzle temp: 195 °C
- Bed temp: 60 °C (instead of 70 °C - I can use 60 °C because of the 0.2 mm initial layer height)
- Retraction 1 mm - 40 mm/s

I then imported the profile into Cura, which has a bit more options.